# Use OAuth to tightly bind two applications?

Tags: architecture, oauth

I'm working to integrate two applications developed by two different teams for the same user base.  The user will be logged into the first, and we'd like their login on the first application to provide them access to the second.  OAuth was suggested as a protocol to execute this integration.  This doesn't strike me as entirely similar to the OAuth implementations that I've seen.

Does it make sense to use OAuth to tightly bind two applications like this?

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends :).

I'd recommend to not use one application as server for OAuth but to separate the login process and both applications should use Oauth for authenticating the user.

In this way both applications don't know about each other, but only about the login service. This enables you to develop other applications which only depend on your OAuth service.